# Predict distributions parameters - algebraic solver

Tags: r, distribution, stan

I'm wondering if there is an R package which can help me to get the correct parameters for a distribution of my choice and for intervals of my choice.

For Instance, [here Betancourt](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gaussian_processes.html#323_Informative_Prior_Model) is looking at inverse gamma and he wants to learn which set of parameters will give >1% below 2 and >1% above 20 (like the graph below). Stan's solver returns the parameters for inv-gamma which results the intervals of interest. Is there any solution applied directly on R?

[image]

Or in other words,

- I have the distribution
- I have the intervals

Can I learn the correct parameters?

Thanks

Comment: qnorm and the equivalents for other distributions is not answering my question